# i want to show data that are coming from ajax response function in ul and li tags?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-lists

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'submenu.php',
        success: function(response) {
            //console.log(response);
            var menuArray = JSON.parse(response);
            var html = "";
            $.each(menuArray, function(key, value) {
                html += "<li><a href=''>" + value.Menu_Name + "</a></li>";
                if (value.subMenu.length > 0) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(value.subMenu));
                    $.each(value.subMenu, function(key, subValue) {
                        html += "<li><a href=''>" + subValue.text + "</a></li>";
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log(html);
            if (response != "") {
                $("#main_menu").html(html);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In this code, my data is coming from a database and I want to show this data in ul and li list like menu and sub menu. how to use ul and li tags in this code to show like a menu bar.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you get menu using AJAX request, if you don't pass parameters to it?
It could mean only that the menu is static, but not dynamic.
And if you trying to get - it is better to use $_GET request, but not $_POST.

Regarding to you question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('submenu.php', function(response) {
        var html = '';

        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            html += '<li>' + value.Menu_Name;          
            if (value.subMenu.length > 0) {
                $.each(value.subMenu, function(subKey, subValue) {
                    html += '<li>' + subValue.text + '</li>';     
                });
            }  
            html += '</li>'
        });

        if (html != '') {
            html = '<ul>' + html + '</ul>';
        }

        $('#main_menu').html(html);

    }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: sir, it is not static. here i define roll id=1 for particular user admin. for checking this function is working or not. now i have a login page in which session variable i have roll id. now i want to send this session variable to menu.php page and form there to submenu.php page. so i get value according to user login. and is also have problem in styling of this data. i want to set this menu in horizontal bar, where submenu come when we go to main menu.